# Extract data from VHD

Tags: windows-server-2008, vhd

I cant attach the vhd to server 2008 disk management as it says the disc is invalid
But it does run in HyperV, but as I need it offline I cant extract it when the hyperV is running.

Any ideas?

Comment: What kind of VHD, did the VM have snapshots, what version of Hyper-V, what is the exact text of the error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

7Zip can read VHD files and extract the contents (though NTFS Extended Attributes and such will be ignored). It can also read disk images with NTFS partitions, as well as WIM files.